# correct for shift from butterworth filter?

Tags: filters, filter-design, lowpass-filter, python

I have implemented a python butterworth filter but it seems to shift the data a lot, the x location of my data is very important to me for my analysis. Is there a way to correct for this shift precisely?

Does it shift all the data uniformly? Or does certain areas get shifted further/less far that others?

Comment: [This answer](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17122/once-again-confusion-between-phase-and-group-delay/17124#17124) might be helpful.

Comment: This is useful, and i believe i am using an FIR filter. Its just a butterworth filter created with scipy.butter

How do i know if my filter is linear-phase and FIR?

Once i determine that is there a way to determine the shift from the filter specifications?

Comment: Your filter is an IIR filter (it has numerator and denominator coefficients called `b` and `a`), so unfortunately there is no constant delay. Different frequencies of the input signal experience different delays.

Comment: Is there a filter that is recommended for creating a bandpass near low frequencies that has a defined shift (or maybe one that reduces shift as much as possible automatically)?

Comment: You can try to design a linear phase FIR filter for the given specifications. However, if you need a steep filter with high stopband attenuation, then the delay will be quite large due to the high filter length.

Answer (score 2):

The delay or "shift" of an IIR butterworth filter varies with frequency.  If you want a constant delay that you can correct for in a simple manner, you need to instead use a linear phase FIR filter, not an IIR filter.